# Time series prediction using GP - training data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, non-linear-regression, genetic-programming

I am trying to implement  time series forecasting using genetic programming. I am creating random trees (Ramped Half-n-Half) with s-expressions and evaluating each expression using RMSE to calculate the fitness. My problem is the training process. If I want to predict gold prices and the training data looked like this:

```
date        open        high        low         close
28/01/2008  90.959999   91.889999   90.75       91.75
29/01/2008  91.360001   91.720001   90.809998   91.150002
30/01/2008  90.709999   92.580002   90.449997   92.059998
31/01/2008  90.919998   91.660004   90.739998   91.400002
01/02/2008  91.75       91.870003   89.220001   89.349998
04/02/2008  88.510002   89.519997   88.050003   89.099998
05/02/2008  87.900002   88.690002   87.300003   87.68
06/02/2008  89          89.650002   88.75       88.949997
07/02/2008  88.949997   89.940002   88.809998   89.849998
08/02/2008  90          91          89.989998   91
```

As I understand, this data is nonlinear so my questions are:

1- Do I need to make any changes to this data like exponential smoothing? and why?

2- When looping the current population and evaluating the fitness of each expression on the training data, should I calculate the RMSE on just part of this data or all of it?

3- When the algorithm finishes and I get an expression with the best (lowest) fitness, does this mean that when I apply any row from the training data, the output should be the price of the next day?

I've read some research papers about this and I noticed some of them mentioning dividing the training data when calculating the fitness and some of them are doing exponential smoothing. However, I found them a bit difficult to read and understand, and most implementations I've found are either in python or R which I am not familiar with.

I appreciate any help on this.
Thank you.